# Angular2 extending component function is showing up as undefined even when service/component is within scope?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using a login component to fire a function that sends the user token for authentication via service. However, the service is showing up as undefined even tho the component recognizes the function data members:

Child Custom Login component:
[image]

HTML of Login (simply calling the login function above via template)
[image]

The Service being called for login (through auth.login from above)
[image]

Extended component of the login to use the NbLoginComponent members in my custom login component, mostly the **auth** from here is being used in my child component.
[image]

Error that I'm getting after hitting login on my login page:
[image]

Comment: You never injected `auth` in the parent component

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just needed AuthenticationService to be used in my child component. but its showing up as undefined after running

Comment: You still need to inject the service in your component constructor or its child constructor. Keep in mind that if you inject it in the child constructor, you will need to inject every other service from the parent as well and pass them in the `super` call.

Comment: Anyway I can straight up inject the service to the child component without having to involve the parent?

Comment: Also im trying to add the super call to the constructor, but syntax is failing. How would the super call look like?

Comment: `super` is the parent constructor. So you child constructor would be :
`construtor(service: NbAuthService, options: {}, cd: ChangeDetectorRef, router: Router, auth: AuthenticationService) {
super(service, options, cd, router);
}`

Comment: core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgxLoginComponent: ([object Object], ?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgxLoginComponent: ([object Object], ?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).

Got this error after adding constructor and super to child.

Comment: Remove `options: {}` from the child constructor, and either pass an empty object to the `super` call, or add the options you want.

Comment: Check this please: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6294072 :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your NgxLoginComponent.

```
constructor(
  private auth: AuthenticationService,
  private service: NbAuthService,
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
  private router: Router,
) {
  super(service, {}, cd, router);
}
```